# BOOST_FOREACH and a vector

Tags: c++, boost, boost-foreach

I have a vector of Scenes, `vector<Scene>`. What is the correct way to iterate over the elements, as reference or not?

For example this:

```
BOOST_FOREACH(Scene scene, mScenes)
{
       .....
}
```

Does the macro copy the Scene for each iteration over the vector, or does it use a reference behind the scenes?

So is it any different from this:

```
BOOST_FOREACH(Scene& scene, mScenes)
{
       .....
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`BOOST_FOREACH` behaves exactly as you tell him, by value, reference or const reference

Answer (score 5):

Your first example *does* copy each `Scene`. Most likely, you want the second. With the first, you can modify `scene` and the vector will be unaffected. If you're not modifying the vector, you should use `const Scene& scene`. If you are, use `Scene &`.

Answer (score 2):

Note that with C++11 you don't need to use BOOST_FOREACH (excepted with some boost libs that return a pair of iterators).

```
for(const Scene& scene: mScenes){}
```

The same rules apply as for BOOST_FOREACH : you most likely want to use const &, rarely &, and never copy.